# module 'scipy.stats' has no attribute 'nanmean'

Tags: python, import, scipy

I'm getting the error mentioned in the title.  I have all of the following three imports in my code:

```
import scipy as sc
import scipy.stats
from scipy import stats
```

But still get the error.  I'm sure it has something to do with the version, but can't figure out either how to make it work or a workaround for "nanmean".  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

nanmean was a deprecated function that was removed from scipy.stats in version 0.18.0.  You will have to either use an older version of SciPy or use the equivalent function from NumPy.

```
from numpy import nanmean
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I use: import numpy.stats as stat, I get this error: No module named 'numpy.stats'.

Comment: My mistake.  Nanmean is not in a stats submodule in NumPy.  You can use that function directly once NumPy is imported

Answer (score 2):

nanmean is also available from scipy module itself, so this might work if you replace

```
from scipy.stats import nanmean
```

with

```
from scipy import nanmean
```